# Maximum modulus of complex polinomial in an open ball

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Hi I'm stuck in this problem:

Let $p\in \mathbb C[z], a\in \mathbb C$ and $r\geq 0$, then exists $z\in D_{r} (a)$ such that $|p(z)|>|p(a)|$.

I'm trying to figure out what to do but I get nothing, a hint would be very apreciated, thanks.

Comment: This sounds amenable to a use of the maximum modulus principle. We know that for any holomorphic function on a closed disk, the maximum and minimum occur on the boundary (unless it is constant). Here, just pick an $r' < r$ and look at the closed disk about $a$ with radius $r'$, then we know that there is some $z$ on the boundary of the disk so that $|p(z)| > |p(a)|$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You could post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I was trying to solve whitout heavy guns, is just a practice problem, I just read a demonstration of the same problem with "<" instead of ">" using continuity and inequalities I'll try to adapt the argument and show it to you, thanks @CameronWilliams